# How to integrate markdown-it-emoji into VS Code

Tags: node.js, markdown, visual-studio-code

VisualStudio Code has great support for Markdown  by using markdown-it, and there is an extension named markdown-it-emoji to allow emojis in markdown directly. I tried to install that in VS Code, but I don't see emojis rendered in the VS Code Preview.

This is what I have done:

- `npm install markdown-it-emoji --save-dev`
- My package.json looks like that

`"devDependencies": { "markdown-it": "^8.3.1", "markdown-it-emoji": "^1.3.0"}`

What do I have to do to use markdown-it-emoji in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on VSCode and maintain the builtin markdown extension. As of VSCode 1.12, you cannot extend VSCode's builtin markdown viewer to support emojis

However, we are exploring allowing extensions to contribute functionality to VSCode's builtin markdown preview: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22916 I've even created an [example extension that adds emoji support to the preview](https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-markdown-emoji). To try the preview extension:

- Make sure you are on VSCode 1.12+
- Install the VSIX from the [extension repo](https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-markdown-emoji)
- Add the setting `"markdown.enableExperimentalExtensionApi": true` to your user or workspace settings

Keep in mind that this functionality is experimental. We have not yet committed to markdown extension extensions yet and the API / functionality may change

Also, please let me know if you are developing a markdown extension extension for VSCode

Comment: I tried to follow your recipe, but I don't see emoji rendered in preview mode. Latest VSCode, installed VSIX (it is displayed as installed extension), added the setting, and restarted VS Code. Tried to use `:white_check_mark:` inside a `*.md` file, but it is not rendered. Do I have to do something additional?

Comment: The vsix may have been out of date. I've published an update to github, but the markdown API is going to change this month so it will break again sometime. Hopefully we'll have the api finalized this month so that you'll be able to download this from the marketplace soon

Comment: Great!! Tried it again, and it works now. Great work!! I will keep it as it works, and when it breaks again, I hope the new API will see the light of day soon. Thank's a lot for a great extension, and your excellent feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

Emoji direct are still unsupported in VSC as of version 1.12.1; See: Emoji Code Extension For VSC by Idleberg | idleberg.emoji-code ... | Includes snippets for inclusion into code (.htm), (.js), (.css), (.ts), (.py) and (.rb) | But, not for (.md) | Standard rendering of :emoji: in (.md) currently unavailable in VSC | Also, cannot raise idleberg snippet at key 'ji' in (.md) either ... :musical_note:

Comment: Nothing at VSC to suggest otherwise C=> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown

Comment: Direct link to Idleberg extension ... C=> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idleberg.emoji-code